# Solve the absolute value inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

$$|x-3|+|6-x| ≤x $$
I tried to solve it with parts for $x<3$, then for $3< x <6$  and for $x>6$ 
I found the set of each and i did the intersection and it resulted $[3,9]$ but I don't know if this is the correct answer. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

By triangle inequality we have $$x\geq |x-3|+|6-x| \geq |x-3+6-x|=3$$
so $x\geq 3$. Now we have $$x-3+|6-x|\leq x $$ so we have $$|6-x|\leq 3$$and thus $$-3\leq 6-x\leq 3$$
which give us ...

Answer (score 0):

write your inequality in the form
$$|x-3|+|x-6|\le x$$
then you have the cases to solve:
$$x\geq 6$$
$$3\le x<6$$
$$x<3$$
the solution is given by $$3\le x\le 9$$

Answer (score 0):

"I tried to solve it with parts for x<3, then for 36"

Perhaps not the slickest way, but it's the way I'd be most comfortable with.

If $x \le 3$ then

$|x-3|+|6-x| = 3-x + 6-x = 9-2x \le x \implies x \ge 3 \implies x = 3$

If $3 \le x \le 6$ then

$|x-3|+|6-x| = x-3 + 6-x = 3 \le x \implies 3 \le x \le 6$.

If $x \ge 6$ then

$|x-3| + |6-x| = x-3 + x -6 = 2x -9 \le x \implies x \le  9\implies 6\le x \le 9$.

So solutions are precisely $3\le x \le 9$.

As I said, not the slickest but very direct and clear.